# Reference count after deleting a literal

Tags: python, cpython, reference-counting

I am new to python and while I was counting the references to the number "3" in the context of embedding Python in C++ I found out a behavior that I was not expecting at all. Can someone explain me what's happening? In the following I just isolated in an interactive Python the strange behavior.

```
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000052
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000085
>>> a = 3
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000053
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000085
>>> a = 4
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000052
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000086
>>> del(4)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    del(4)
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot delete literal
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000051
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000086
```

I was expecting that deleting a literal would rise an error but i was not expecting that as side effect the reference counting of another literal would change. In contrast, the following set of command do what expected:

```
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000051
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000085
>>> a = 3
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000052
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000085
>>> a = 4
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000051
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000086
>>> del(4)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    del(4)
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot delete literal
>>> sys.getrefcount(3)
1000000051
>>> sys.getrefcount(4)
1000000086
```

So it seems that somehow there is a dandling reference to the object "3" left by the first error in the first code which is cleared by issuing "del(4)". How can i use sys.getrefcount() in order to count the references to a "3" created by PyLong_FromLong(3) in my c ++ code embedding python with this uncertainity on the result?

Comment: Please add your code in a structured way

Comment: Done, sorry but really first post so i got some time to figure out why first post was so badly formatted :)

Comment: Deleting a literal is something I've never considered even doing, let alone protect myself from doing.

Comment: Please explain what exactly it is you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: In CPython, literals like 3 and 4 are singleton objects, and it is not certain who is using them, especially in interactive mode. Therefore, their reference count will behave unexpectedly. The increase or decrease in count in your attempts also has nothing to do with `del`. It's just caused by something else. And we can't determine who, because there are too many possibilities.

Comment: Note that the refcount you're getting is wrong anyway (it starts from a base value way higher than the actual number of references due to https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/121f1f893a39d0b58d3d2b5597505c154ecaac2a), and it will soon contain no information beyond "this is an immortal object" due to [PEP 683](https://peps.python.org/pep-0683/).